# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 2.10 — two questions

Tags: convex-analysis

The solution of the exercise 2.10 from the textbook *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandenberghe, they say that the set:

---

$\{\hat{x} + tv \space |\space  \alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma \le 0\}$

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space$  with $\alpha = v^T Av, \space \beta = b^Tv + 2\hat{x}^T Av, \space and \space \gamma = c + b^T \hat{x} + \hat{x}^TA \hat{x} $

is convex if $\alpha \ge 0$. This is true for any $v$, if $v^T Av \ge 0$ for all $v$, i.e, $A \succeq 0$

---

I don't understant why "(the set) is convex if $\alpha \ge 0$." and why "This is true for any $v$, if $v^T Av \ge 0$ for all $v$, i.e, $A \succeq 0$".

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\alpha \ge 0$, the quadratic function is convex,

The set of $t$ where $\alpha t^2 +\beta t + \gamma \le 0$ can be written in the form of $p \le t \le q$ where $p$ and $q$ are the roots of the quadratic polynomial, $q \ge p$. The correponding $\hat{x}+tv$ is a line segment.

If $\alpha < 0$, the corresponding set is the union of $\{t:t > q\}$ and $\{t:t <p\} $, which is not convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see why $\alpha$ needs to be greater than or equal to 0. If you don't mind I have two more questions 1) why is $\alpha$ positive for all $v$ if $v^T Av \ge 0$ ? 2) Does your answer means that we can rewrite $\{\hat{x}+tv \space | \space \alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma \le \}$ as $\{t \space | \space \alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma \le \}$ ?

Comment: 1) $\alpha$ is defined to be $v^TAv$. It is nonnegative if $v^TAv$ is nonnegative. 2), No, I mean $\{\hat{x}+tv|\alpha t^2+\beta t+\gamma \le 0\} = \{\hat{x}+tv | p \le t \le q\}$ when $\alpha \ge 0$. It is a line segment.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it now.